# Android Animation - applytransformation - Do a camera translate on Z axes for half the time

Tags: android, animation, rotation, cube, depth

I was trying to make a rotational cube using translations and rotations. I'm using a classe named Rotate3dAnimation.java provided in the Google samples. The rotation is working pretty well and i was working about making the illusion of depth on the cube while rotating making it go further and closer from the screen.
To do this i was modifying the method `applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)` but the problem is that, the face of the cube (the one hiding while rotating) has to a movement of going further for the first half of the time, come close again at the second half.

Resuming:

```
Camera.translate(float x, float y, float z)
```

The z translate should be decreasing for the first half and increasing the second half.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final String orientation = mOrientation;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    float midTime = getDuration()/2;
    if (mReverse) {
      camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, (interpolatedTime<midTime)? 
           (mDepthZ * interpolatedTime): (mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime)));

    } else {

      camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, (interpolatedTime<midTime)? 
           (mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime)): (mDepthZ * interpolatedTime));

    }
    if(orientation.equals("horizontal"))
        camera.rotateY(degrees);
    else
        camera.rotateX(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

But i dont think this is working very well... Any sugestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem and after some debugging, I realized that interpolatedTime is not in milliseconds as I (and I am guessing you) expected. This is nice so you don't really have to calculate what the midTime really is, you just need to know the progress of the interpolation.

To check if you're halfway through with the animation just use

`(interpolatedTime < .5)`

in your ternary statement.